# How I find sufficient statistic for Student-t distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

how can I find sufficient statistics for student-t distribution (centred in 0)

Comment: So you want a sufficient statistic for the degrees of freedom, based on an i.i.d. sample from Student's distribution?

Comment: yes! Do you know how I find ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe this question would fare better at stats (dot) stackexchange (dot) com. $\qquad$

Comment: There isn't one that contains a single value. $f_x(x) = \frac{\Gamma((m+1)/2)}{\sqrt{m\pi}\Gamma(m/2)}(1+\frac{x^2}{m})^{-(m+1)/2}$

$f_{\underline x}(\underline x) = [\frac{\Gamma((m+1)/2)}{\sqrt{m\pi}\Gamma(m/2)}]^n \prod_i(1+\frac{x_i^2}{m})^{-(m+1)/2} $

You cannot break the x's , hence a sufficient statistic must contain all the sample values, for example the order-statistic $(x_{(1)}, ... , x_{(n)})$